# Overriding testNG.xml suite parameter with Jenkin parameter value through Maven goals

Tags: testng

Trying to override testNG.xml suite parameter with Jenkins parameter value. But values are not getting replaced. Want to replace the testNG parameters with Jenkin parameter. Can someone please guide. Version used TestNG '7.5' and Open JDK '15'

Maven goals : clean compile test  -DtestNGXml=${testNGXml} -DenvironmentName=${environmentName} -DenvironmentClientID=${environmentClientID}

TestNG.xml

```
<suite name="HealthCheck_Suite" parallel="classes" thread-count=“1”>
    <parameter name="environmentName" value="DEV" />
    <parameter name="environmentClientID" value="BE11TEST" />
    <test name="iOS_HealthCheck">
        <classes>
            <class name="MobileLoginTest">
                <methods>
                    <include name="loginHealthCheckScript" />
                </methods>
            </class>            
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Pom Xml surefire plugin:

````
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
   <configuration>
      <argLine>-javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"</argLine>
      <suiteXmlFiles>
         <suiteXmlFile>${testNGXml}</suiteXmlFile>
      </suiteXmlFiles>
   </configuration>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
         <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
         <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
         <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</plugin>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simplified setup that should work for you.

Lets assume that your test looks like below:

```java
package com.rationaleemotions;

import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class AppTest {

    @Test
    @Parameters({"environmentName", "environmentClientID"})
    public void testMethod(String environmentName, String environmentClientID) {
        System.err.println("EnvironmentName: " +
            environmentName + ", environmentClientID: " + environmentClientID);
    }
}
```

A suite xml would look like below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="jenkins_Suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="1">
  <parameter name="environmentName" value="DEV"/>
  <parameter name="environmentClientID" value="BE11TEST"/>
  <test name="jenkins_test">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.rationaleemotions.AppTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

I have a TestNG dependency of `7.6.1` and my surefire-plugin configuration looks like below:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
  <configuration>
    <suiteXmlFiles>
      <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
    </suiteXmlFiles>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I now create a parameterised job, that basically has 2 string parameters:

1. `env` - This represents the environment
2. `clientId` - This represents the client id

The maven goal would look like below

```
clean test -DenvironmentName="${env}" -DenvironmentClientID="${clientId}"
```

This should now let you override the parameter values defined in your suite xml file, via JVM arguments.

This is possible because TestNG already lets you override values in `<parameter>` tags via JVM arguments.

So:

- `<parameter name="environmentName" value="DEV"/>` - Can be overridden via `-DenvironmentName`
- `<parameter name="environmentClientID" value="BE11TEST"/>` - Can be overridden via `-DenvironmentClientID`

Comment: Thank you Krishnan Mahadevan.  I have one question about parameter annotation in test class. Is it mandatory?  As these are suite level parameters and needed for every test method so it is not feasible to update at each test method level.

Comment: In that case, you would need to create a helper method for each of the paramater, which when invoked from within a `@Test` method, it would return back `Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getTestContext().getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("myParameter");`